# Echo all meta keys of a custom-post TYPE

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

Is there a way to dump a list of all meta keys being used by all posts belonging to a custom post type?

I.e., a post-type named foods, each food (ham, spaghetti, chicken), can have a different meta key, which is generated dynamically. 
I can't know which meta keys have been added, but I'd like to be able to use a list of all of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a simple query to get a distinct list of user-entered meta_keys for a specific post type, then cache the results using the Transients API. The meta keys from this query will be those that do not start with an underscore or number.

```
function generate_foods_meta_keys(){
    global $wpdb;
    $post_type = 'foods';
    $query = "
        SELECT DISTINCT($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key) 
        FROM $wpdb->posts 
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta 
        ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = '%s' 
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key != '' 
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key NOT RegExp '(^[_0-9].+$)' 
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key NOT RegExp '(^[0-9]+$)'
    ";
    $meta_keys = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($query, $post_type));
    set_transient('foods_meta_keys', $meta_keys, 60*60*24); # create 1 Day Expiration
    return $meta_keys;
}
```

To get a list of meta_keys in your template for generating your dropdown, use the following function:

```
function get_foods_meta_keys(){
    $cache = get_transient('foods_meta_keys');
    $meta_keys = $cache ? $cache : generate_foods_meta_keys();
    return $meta_keys;
}

$meta_keys = get_foods_meta_keys();
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. I'll need to figure out how to exclude some wordpress-included, behind the scenes meta values, but that's another question!

Comment: Are all of the meta keys you are looking for created without a prepended underscore?

Comment: no underscore. should they have one to make it easier? Or a prefix?
Basically, all items I do not want are either numbers or start with an underscore. the rest are useful to me.

Comment: Meta keys that start with an underscore are hidden from the custom fields interface. Let me see if I can whip up a query that adjusts to this.

Comment: Check out my latest edit. That should work dandy.

Comment: almost works! The results that are simply numbers are still appearing.

Comment: Try it again. I added another regex in there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd have to first do a query to gather up all the meta keys for all the custom post type into an array. So something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom-post-type-name',
    );
$cpts = new WP_Query($args);
if($cpts->have_posts()) : while($cpts->have_posts() ) : $cpts->the_post();
    $meta_values[] = get_post_meta($post->ID);
endwhile; endif;
```

All your meta values will be stored in an the `$meta_values` array.

You could do a `var_dump($meta_values)` to look at the contents of the array to be sure.

Comment: works but gets heavy... if multiple posts have identical keys, you get the same key many times. I wonder if there's any way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_post_custom`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) to get all keys and values.

There is also a function called [`get_post_custom_keys()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_keys) which you can use to retrieve all of the meta keys.

Comment: please read the question, it clearly asks for a solution for a cpt not a specific post!