# How to get the meta box name and value

Tags: metabox

I have several meta field like

Property Name----->bla bla,
Property ID-------->1234,
Property Address--->bla bla bla ,

and so on .

I want to print all the meta box name and their value . How can I do that ?

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58834/echo-all-meta-keys-of-a-custom-post-type

Comment: Please specify in your request if you mean to a specific post, post type or some sort of filter to narrow the list or if you wish to list all used meta fields to your site.

Comment: @codearachnid

I meant a specifc post type . Like If I have a pos type "property" and I have several meta box for that like "Property Name","Property Address","Property Value" and so on  . If I put the value of "Property Name" to "xyz" "Property Address" to "abc" "Property Value" to "1000" . I want to print  name of meta box and their value like 

"Prperty Name"-->"abc" 
"Property Address"-->"xyz"
"Property Value"--->1000 
and so on . I can get only a specific meta box value by get_post_meta() function , but I want those info as I mentioned .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to build a way to display a group of meta fields for your custom post type. Using [`get_post_custom`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) you can fetch all the custom post meta for a single post in 1 request. Then using a combination of looping you can build your output as you see fit. A roughed in example of how this can be accomplished is below:

```
wpse_157410_custom_meta_box( $display_fields = array(), $ID = null, $echo = true ) {

    // if provided $ID is null fetch the current post
    $ID = is_null( $ID ) ? get_the_ID() : $ID;
    $output = '';
    $row_template = apply_filters( 'wpse_157410_custom_meta_box/row_template', '<div><label>%s</label><span>%</span></div>' );
    $values_delimiter = apply_filter( 'wpse_157410_custom_meta_box/values_delimiter', ',' ):
    $custom_post_meta = get_post_custom( $ID );

    foreach( $custom_post_meta as $key => $values ){

        $title = '';
        if( array_key_exists( $key, $display_fields ) || empty( $display_fields ) ){
            $title = empty( $display_fields ) ? $key : $display_fields[ $key ];
        }

        // skip to the next record if we can't display a title
        if( empty( $title ) )
            continue;

        $value = implode( $values_delimiter, $values );
        $output .= apply_filters( 'wpse_157410_custom_meta_box/row_template', 
            sprintf( $row_template, $title, $value ), 
            $values, 
            $key, 
            $ID,
            $custom_post_meta, 
            $display_fields
            );
    }

    output = apply_filter( 'wpse_157410_custom_meta_box/output', $output, $custom_post_meta, $ID, $display_fields, $echo ):

    if( $echo ) {
        echo $output;
    } else {
        return $output;
    }
}
```

To display this in your template you can just make a simple array of your field group. Decorate with the appropriate tags and then just drop the method into place and it'll build the field output:

```
// get the meta group for the current post (for a specific post 
// just supply the $post_id as the second argument)
$field_group = array(
    'property_name' => 'Property Name',
    'property_address' => 'Property Address',
    'property_value' => 'Property Value'
    );
wpse_157410_custom_meta_box( $field_group );
```